# JsonObject.get gives java.lang.NullPointerException. How to handle the when keys are not there

Tags: java, json

I am using minimal-json-0.9.5.jar in my javacode. I am retrieving the json from API in java and process it.  ObObj.get("subObligations").asArray() gives NullPointerException error.

JsonArray SubObArr1=ObObj.get("subObligations").asArray();

ObObj contains array "subobligations" with small letter. The content has both subobligations and subObligations.

ObObj.get("subObligations").isNull() is not helpful. this also gives same error. how to handle the jsonobject when it does have not key.

Comment: Basically, use `== null` to check for a null reference...

Comment: @JonSkeet It did work. I always thinking about checking with IsNull and missed to use ==null. Thanks for the answer.